# Determine if a file contains a string in C

Tags: c, string, file-processing, word-processor

How can I check if a given `FILE*` contains a string in C running on Linux (if it matters)?

The string must consist of the whole line it's on. For example, this:

```
jfjfkjj
string
jfjkfjk
```

would be true; but this:

```
jffjknf
fklm...string...lflj
jfjkfnj
```

wouldn't. I'm essentially looking for an internal alternative to `system("grep -x file")`

Comment: Read line by line and compare.

Comment: You can use functions like `getline` and `strcmp`, etc.

Comment: @lurker Okay, I'll read their manpages.

Comment: `while(fgets( ....) != NULL)` and remember to [remove any trailing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221).

Comment: @WeatherVane I just now saw your comment, that's indeed the code I came up with just now. I know this is somewhat off-topic, but what's the difference between `while(fgets( ....) != NULL)` and `while(!fgets( ....))`?

Comment: There is no functional difference, but there are questions which ask if `NULL` is guaranteed to be `0`. Using `NULL` makes the code more readable as it is clear that comparison is for a pointer. Suppose your pointers are 64-bit but `int` is 32-bit. Does `!fgets` create more work at runtime, or will a good compiler do the work for you?

Comment: system("file fname");

Comment: @WeatherVane Of course `while(fgets( ....) != NULL)` and `while(!fgets( ....))` are different.  Certainly OP meant to compare `while(fgets( ....) != NULL)` and `while(fgets( ....))`  - no `!`.  In this 2nd code comparison, if `NULL` is 0 or not is immaterial as they both function the same.  The _null pointer constant_ `NULL`, if not already a _null pointer_, is converted to one before the compare.

Comment: @chux brain fart. OP's `while(!fgets( ....))` was wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yeah you're right I meant `while(fgets( ....))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reads a file line by line and checks if the line matches the string supplied in argument 1 (`argv[1]`) after every read. If so, it sets the bool `infile` (bools defined in `<stdbool.h>`) to true.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv[]) {
    char    *filepath = "/path/to/file";
    bool    infile = false;
    char    *line = NULL;
    size_t  len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    FILE    *fp = fopen(filepath, "r");

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s\n", filepath);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
        if (!strcmp(line, argv[1])) {
            infile = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(uuidfp);

    if (line)
        free(line);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're looking to improve performance, you might want to hash the target line and compare the hash to each line in the file first. You'll still need to do the `strcmp()` in case of hash collisions, but collisions should be rare, unless you expect adversarial input.

Comment: @EOF I wouldn't expect that'd be worth the trouble.

Comment: @SteveSummit I'd expect it depends. An even simpler test would be to use the return value of `getline()`, which must either be `strlen(argv[1])` or `strlen(argv[1])+1` for the strings to possibly be equal.

Comment: A reasonable solution, but has no report about whether the string from `argv[1]` was found in the file. And it has a flaw that you failed to check `argc` to ensure there is an `argv[1]` supplied. Moreover, the `main` argument is incorrect; `char **argv[]` should be either `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`.

Comment: @EOF [2nd idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51068916/determine-if-a-file-contains-a-string-in-c#comment89130023_51069789) is a good one.

Comment: Minor point: `free(NULL)` is OK so `if (line)
        free(line);` can be `free(line);`.  No functional problem leaving it as is either.  Close to a style issue.

Comment: Using `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;` is a nice one-liner to remove the `'\n'`which can spend time checking each element of the string.   Yet code does have the line length `read` for an even faster test.

Comment: @EOF I ended up using strcasecmp() in my program, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: `strcmp` for some reason doesn't work for me. I used: `strstr(line, argv[1]) != NULL` instead.